# IE 11 - How to prevent checkbox from becoming checked after it has been clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

This is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R1 C1</td>
        <td>R1 C2</td>
        <td><input class="CB" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R2 C1</td>
        <td>R2 C2</td>
        <td><input class="CB" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R3 C1</td>
        <td>R3 C2</td>
        <td><input class="CB" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R4 C1</td>
        <td>R4 C2</td>
        <td><input class="CB" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R5 C1</td>
        <td>R5 C2</td>
        <td><input class="CB" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is JavaScript:

```
      $(".CB").change(function (e)
    {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
            $(this).attr("checked", returnVal);
        }
    }
    );
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mm34ujs/)

**This is related to IE 11**.

As you can see when you click on unchecked checkbox it becomes checked and then confirmation dialog appears. If you don't answer "OK" checkbox reverts back to being unchecked.

It works as expected in Chrome but not in IE11 (FWIW it doesn't work in FF 52 either)

How to modify this so that when you click unchecked checkbox it stays unchecked until OK is pressed on confirmation dialog?

Also: is it acceptable to use class name "CB" even though it is not actually defined anywhere? It works as far as I can tell but it may be a bad practice for reasons I am not aware of.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the behavior you describe.  The box remains unchecked for me until the dialog is confirmed.

Comment: It's fine to use whatever you want for your class names, though general convention is to use lowercase names. Even better would be to use something more descriptive like 'checkbox' rather than 'CB' to make it easier for other developers who might be looking at your code (or you, when coming back to it) can figure out your intentions.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - this is for IE 11. OP updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the event not being able to be cancelled or overruled in IE11, for this reason I have explicitly set checked to false each time and setting it according to it's previous state and the confirm response value.

```js
$(".CB").on('change', function(e) {
  const checked = this.checked // save the previous state
  this.checked = false // uncheck the box every time
  this.checked = checked && confirm('Are you sure?') // set the new state
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="CB" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention - I am targeting IE 11 and in IE 11 it doesn't work (same for FF). It does work in Chrome. I updated OP.

Comment: Try that, it's working in IE11 here. I had to explicitly set the attribute in both instances as the change event can't be canceled.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Dialog is open and checkbox appears checked.

Comment: @JoeSchmoe try that. I'm sure it was working for me last night, but I did have a few drinks. ;-)

Comment: Yep, the latest version does it. Thanks.